# What ENV variables can be set in udev rules?

Tags: udev

Recently I discovered the `ENV{REMOVE_CMD}` variable, which removes the need for using the `ACTION=="remove"` match in the case you need both `add` and `remove`. I was trying to find some info on other useful variables that can be set in udev rules, but unfortunately I couldn't find anything of value.

Does any one know a list where all the `ENV` variables can be found?

Comment: for the sake of clarity, the official name for "ENV variable" is "device property", not to be confused with "device attribute", [see](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that the `ENV` variables are pretty free-form and [bound to devices](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/udev.html#ENV%7Bkey%7D). The only enforced restrictions is that none of these keys may be [be used](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v220/src/udev/udev-rules.c#L1256): ACTION, SUBSYSTEM, DEVTYPE, MAJOR, MINOR, DRIVER, IFINDEX, DEVNAME, DEVLINKS, DEVPATH, TAGS.

Other than that, interpretation of the environment variables is left to other rules and programs. Use `grep -rni 'ENV{' /{lib,etc}/udev/rules.d` to find the consumers and providers of environment variables. In your specific `REMOVE_CMD` case, the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules` is responsible for handling this action:

```
# run a command on remove events
ACTION=="remove", ENV{REMOVE_CMD}!="", RUN+="$env{REMOVE_CMD}"
ACTION=="remove", GOTO="default_end"
```

With this command you can find more environment variables:

```
grep -hrPo 'ENV{\K[^}]*(?=}=[^=])' /{etc,lib}/udev/rules.d | sort -u
```

As an example, consider the `95-upower-hid.rules` file. This file sets the `UPOWER_BATTERY_TYPE` variable. No other rules use this file, but the [UPower](http://upower.freedesktop.org/) daemon registers to udevd for add/change/remove events. Then when an event occurs, UPower specifically queries the device for this variable in order to determine whether it should treat is as regular mice, UPSes or Unifying receiver devices.

Another (more useful) example is the `UDISKS_IGNORE` environment variable which can be used to hint graphical file browsers to hide the device in the drives list. Specifically for udisks2, you can find the variables in [udisks(8)](http://udisks.freedesktop.org/docs/latest/udisks.8.html#id-1.2.2.7) manual page (located this using `man -K UDISKS_IGNORE`).